# How can hide text-view in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am working on a article application where there are different categories that are shown in navigation drawer.
I had set a text-view for all my fragment but i need when my first fragment that is on displaypostion = 0 that time my text-view will be visibility should be hide and when other fragment are open the text-view property goes to visible. 
here is my code -

```
public class MainActivitySlider extends Activity {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;

// slide menu items
private String[] navMenuTitles;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_slider);
    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customactionbar, null);
    TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8")));
    Typeface fontt = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    mTitleTextView.setTypeface(fontt);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setIcon(
               new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
    final TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface fontt1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(fontt1);
    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    // Find People
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    // Photos

    // Recycle the typed array
    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    // setting the nav drawer list adapter
    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.dd2, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            if()
            txt.setText(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            //txt.setText(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
         @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }

}

/**
 * Slide menu item click listener
 * */
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main3, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.action_location_found:
        hidetext(); 
    return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void hidetext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivitySlider.this, SearchResultsActivity
            .class);
    startActivity(i);

}

/* *
 * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
 */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new OneFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new TwoFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want a textview to be hidden when one (a certain fragment) is shown and visible when the other fragments are shown? If thats the case i would do this:

In your main activity include a Interface called onShownListener that looks like this.

```
public interface OnShownListener{
    public void onShown();
}
```

next add this to the fragment that you want to have control over the textview;

```
OnShownListener listener;
```

and:

```
public void setOnShownListener(OnShownListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

next in your MainActivity where you declare the fragment (in your switch) add this:

```
//you have your switch
switch(pos){
case 1:
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        fragment.setOnShownListener(new OnShownListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShown() {
             //execute my code here.          
            }
        });
break;
//
//
//the rest of your switch..
}
```

Now in your fragment onCreateView - (or anywhere) - you can just call:

```
listener.onShown();
```

and it will alert your activity. so just add your myTextView.setVisibillity(View.INVISIBLE); This has worked for me over and over with many different situations. If i mis-read or misunderstood what you're trying to say, let me know. Don't just down-rate the post without letting me know :)